# NullPointer Exception when accessing map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on a map inside a fragment class.

In the layout file I have declared the map as follows:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And then in the onCreateView method from the fragment, I have include the following:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


        mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        mapView.onResume();

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                map = mMap;
                map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowOrigen(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())));
                // For showing a move to my location button
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    return;
                }
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager
                        .getBestProvider(criteria, false));


                if (location != null) {
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                                    .getLongitude()), 14));
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

Now I need to add markers or trace a route on the map, but  I get NullPointer Exception when making any reference to the map.

Like here:

```
 //LAS DOS DIRECCIONES
        if (!direccion_origen.equals("...En espera...")){

            estado_actual = "1";
            if (!direccion_destino.equals("...En espera...")){

                estado_actual = "3";
                btnorigen.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                btndestino.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
        java.lang.NullPointerException ->       map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                        .title("Marker in Sydney"));
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
            }
        }
```

What should I do to add a map marker in my code?

Comment: Don't call the `MapView`'s lifecycle methods yourself.  (Or for that matter, any Android lifecycle method.)

Comment: when do you call addMarker? please show your code in detail

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @redAllocator, I have put the call in my question, the last piece of code

Comment: You should not call `mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` or         `mapView.onResume()`, at least not here.  If you've fully reimplemented `MapFragment`, you should call those methods only from the same lifecycle methods of the fragment.

Comment: you should wait until both OnMapReadyCallback have completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to call `getMapAsync` every time you need a reference to the map.  The minuscule performance difference will not be noticed.

Comment: I have tried as you propose, but then the map is not shown

Comment: I have used following function and it works now: map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        public void onMapLoaded() {
           //do stuff here
        }
    });

Answer (score 1):

You should wait until both OnMapReadyCallback have completed.

```
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                    map = mMap;
                    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowOrigen(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())));
                    // For showing a move to my location button
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        return;
                    }
                    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                        .title("Marker in Sydney"));
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
                }
```